Present Value of Business School
John is 30 years old at the beginning of the new millennium and is thinking
about getting an MBA. John is currently making 40,000 per year and expects
the same for the remainder of his working years (until age 65). I f he goes to a
business school, he gives up his income for two years and, in addition, pays
$20,000 per year for tuition. In return, John expects an increase in his salary
after his MBA is completed. Suppose that the post-graduation salary increases
at a 5% per year and that the discount rate is 8%. What is minimum expected
starting salary after graduation that makes going to a business school a positiveNPV investment for John? For simplicity, assume that all cash flows occur at the
end of each year.
Should you include John's lost salary from the two years in business school in the cash flow calculations? Us couple of young chaps here are disagreeing.

His forgone income is part of his opportunity cost of education, so it should be in the equation somewhere. You'll have to be more explicit with the cash flow you're calculating if you want a more helpful answer.
